# C++ (Logical Copy Constructor) How do I copy an object?

Tags: c++, pointers, object, copy-constructor

I have a class:

```
class Person{
public:
    Person();
    ~Person();
    string name;
    int* age;
};

int main()
{
    Person* personOne = new Person;
    personOne->name = "Foo";
    personOne->age = new int(10);


    return 0;
}
```

How do I create another object of Person that copies all of personOne data? The age pointer needs to be pointing to a new int so whenever the age changes in personOne or personTwo, it doesn't affect each other.

Comment: I hope this is a purely academic question, and that you'd never write real code like that.

Comment: don't worry, you haven't seem my "real" program yet ;) it is nothing like this. This is just a code example I've made. If this were my real code, I would have a proper constructor, assigning varibles correctly, deleteing pointers and etc etc (won't even use a pointer for the age lol)

Comment: No: If you had a real program, it shouldn't have pointers or `new` at all! :-)

Comment: @kerrekSB that is very true, but this kind of optimization is just beyond me :P

Comment: It's not optimisation -- it's just C++. What you have looks like more like Java...

Comment: @KerrekSB now I'm totally lost... how does that look like java... I dunno...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two posibilites:

- copy constructor + assignment operator
- `clone` method

Code:

```
class Person{
public:
    Person();
    ~Person();
    Person (const Person& other) : name(other.name), age(new int(*(other.age)))
    {
    }
    Person& operator = (const Person& other)
    {
        name = other.name;
        delete age; //in case it was already allocated
        age = new int(*(other.age))
        return *this;
    }
    //alternatively 
    Person clone()
    {
        Person p;
        p.name = name;
        p.age = new int(age);
        return p;
    }

    string name;
    int* age;
};
```

**Answer these before going forward:**

- do you really need an `int` pointer?
- are you aware of smart pointers?
- do you free all memory you allocate?
- do you initialize all members in the constructor?

Comment: Thanks for the example. Can I ask is that the copy constructor + assignment operator or clone method?

Comment: You forgot to clean up the memory allocated for this->age in the assignment operator.

Comment: I don't really need an int pointer, but the code I've shown is just an very small example of what I wanted to do in the future. What are smart pointers? and yes i forgot to delete the pointers lol

Comment: Can't you move the `age` initialization (more like assignment) to alongside `name`?

Comment: @chris this /\ what you mean?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, Yes, figured that'd be better.

Comment: @chris definitely, I don't know why I didn't write that from the start.

Comment: neither alternative you propose is good. **A class that does resource management should have that as its sole responsibility**. Use a value type, or smart-pointers should be the top 2 suggestions